# Can i use different database, only for user administration in a webapp?

Tags: database, authentication

I have an webapp for manage consentings,   and i dont want to manage users in that app, and i want to know if its a good pratice manage users using other plataforms, using diferent database.

Comment: Can you use a different database? Yes. Is it good practice? Primarily based on opinion unfortunately. What risks are you trying to mitigate?

Comment: I want to focus on consentings, and use some CMS to handle users?